# EC2 instance running Rails app becomes unreachable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have a rails app running on several EC2 instances (using instance storage, not EBS).  Frequently (more often than it seems like it should), an instance becomes unreachable (cannot ping or ssh, and Amazon ELB reports it as out of service).  However, in the AWS console the instance still shows up as "running."  Rebooting the instance doesn't help -- once an instance gets into this unreachable state, I can reboot it successfully, but it continues to be unreachable after reboot.  The only alternative is to terminate it and start a new instance.

Any ideas why this might be occurring?  Unfortunately I can't access the logs on the instance once it becomes unreachable, and my monitoring software does not show any spikes in any particular metric right before the instance becomes unreachable.  The System Log for the instance that I can access through the AWS console is not informative (it seems to boot up fine).

Comment: That is very odd behavior. Are you sure it is not your OS having issues? Are you spinning up entirely new OS instances, or just a snapshot of what you have? Perhaps you should run another default instance (not running anything) side by side with your current instance and see if it exhibits the same issues.

Comment: I'm spinning up entirely new instances from a stock Ubuntu AMI, and then using rubber to install the appropriate packages, configure apache, deploy the app, etc.  So it must be something with my app or my config -- it doesn't seem like it could be anything with the underlying hardware because it keeps happening.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to answer without seeing the server.  However, you can inspect the hard drive of the instance by stopping it, unmounting the EBS drive from it and attaching it to a live instance.  Then, use the live instance to look at the system logs.  I'd look to see if the hard drive filled up (which could easily seize the server).  If not, I'd look into the system logs to see if errors were reported.

Comment: The instances are using instance storage instead of EBS, so once the instance is unreachable I don't think I can access the disk.  My monitoring of the instances suggests that disk usage was not the problem (since it wasn't particularly high before the instance became unreachable).